# Is it possible to use one .ovpn profile for multiple remotes?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

**How can i configure OvpnServers/.ovpn profiles to have the ability to connect to two remote servers?**
Goal: I want user to be able to have one .ovpn profile to connect to OVPn Server A or OVPn Server B.

For example i've installed [OpenVPN server with this sh script](https://github.com/angristan/openvpn-install) on **Machine A** and **Machine B**.

Then ive generated an **.ovpn profile** on **Machine A**.
Now profile have 1 remote - **Machine A**.
Then i've replaced the remote to **Machine B**.

Now profile (generated on **Machine A**) cannot connect to **Machine B**.

What ive tried so far:
Created two identical profiles on both machines and added remote to both and fiddled with adding multiple CA, Certs etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking to turn Basic mode Off for the OpenVPN Connect Client.

This is described in the OpenVPN article
[Multiple connection profiles - vpn.client.basic](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/vpn-client-basic/):

> If the Connect Client is configured not to run in the basic mode, then the 'import' function is available, you can manually delete connection profiles from the Connect Client, and you can have the Connect Client remember multiple servers so you can switch easily from one server to the next.

See the article for instructions for Windows and the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to include multiple "remote" clauses in a single OVPN file. When OpenVPN is started with such file, it will cycle between the "remote" clauses until a connection is established. It will not attempt to connect to two or more of them at the same time.

These multiple "remote" clauses may represent different connection partners (servers), but they have to have in common:

- Authentication method and credentials (be it username/password pair, client certificate or both)
- Server certificates issued by a single certificate authority
- Mode of operation (tun/tap)
- Compatible IP settings
- Maybe other things as well

In short, this is used to connect to one of a multiple servers or different IPs of the same server.

I am not aware of any possibility to choose between the "remote" clauses of a single ovpn file when starting the tunnel.

Neither it is possible to make it connect to more than one server with a single ovpn file.

Comment: So if user certificates are generated by 'easyrsa build-client-full' i can theoretically create one server certificate and use it in easy-rsa on both machines?

Comment: @DmitriiS. now I understand your question. Yes, most users do exactly this, I suppose. It doesn't matter how the certificate is issued, what is important is that each of the two parties has the CA certificate needed to authenticate its peer. The certificates of both peers may or may not be issued by the same CA.